# Pandas split rows according to column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a pandas dataframe with some columns, and the column 'input_text' has around 8K words for each row. My purpose is to split each row into more rows, each one having 500 words from the original row's input_text.
For example, if we used 2 words instead of 500, this row:

```
a | b | c | d | input_text
1   2   3   4       'Hello this is text hello how r u'
```

would be transformed into 4 rows:

```
a | b | c | d | input_text
1   2   3   4       'Hello this'
a | b | c | d | input_text
1   2   3   4       'is text'
a | b | c | d | input_text
1   2   3   4       'hello how'
a | b | c | d | input_text
1   2   3   4       'r u'
```

But I need this to work for 500 words.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# function
```

NOTE! The dataframe I use is really big, so speed is very important here.

Comment: What are the conditions?

Comment: What conditions?

Comment: Is it just two words at a time?

Comment: For a long text, each row should have 500 words only, and they should be in the consecutive order that they appeared in the original full text.

Comment: I gave the example for 2 words because it was easier to illustrate my point, but yeah, essentially for 500 words.

Comment: @petar What if the sentence could not get evenly divided into `2 words`? What happens to remaining words?

Comment: They are just put in the last row, irrespective of the fact that they can't be evenly divided. But please note that I need this split by 500 words, not 2.I just gave the example with 2 words because it's easier to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def splitter(input_text,n=2):
  values = input_text.split()
  return [values[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(values), n)]

df['input_text'] = df['input_text'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:splitter(x))
df = df.explode('input_text')
df['input_text'] = df['input_text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

Comment: This is the solution that I ultimately started using. Thank you and thanks to all the other guys who answered correctly! Have a good day.

Comment: Combining this with the regex usage below might be a good idea to cover cases with multiple blank spaces between words

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
print(df)

   a  b  c  d                        input_text
0  1  2  3  4  Hello this is text hello how r u
```

#### Approach with `findall` and `explode`

```
df['input_text'] = df['input_text'].str.findall(r'((?:\S+\s?){1,2})(?:\s|$)')
df = df.explode('input_text')
```

**Regex details**

- `((?:\S+\s?){1,2})`: First capturing group

  - `(?:\S+\s?)`: Non capturing group

    - `\S+\s?` : Matches one or more non-whitespace characters followed by zero or one whitespace
    - `{1, 2}`: Matches the previous token between one or two times
- `(?:\s|$)` : Non capturing group

  - `\s|$` : Matches a single whitespace character or assert position at the end of line

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yn45vB/1)

#### Result

```
print(df)

   a  b  c  d  input_text
0  1  2  3  4  Hello this
0  1  2  3  4     is text
0  1  2  3  4   hello how
0  1  2  3  4         r u
```

Note: In order to split by `500` words replace `2` in the regex pattern with `500`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
First split the words into list and store that in a column. You can change the number_to_split to 500 for splitting to 500

```
number_to_split =2
def split_text(string):
    words = string.split()
    grouped_words = [' '.join(words[i: i + number_to_split]) for i in range(0, len(words),number_to_split)]
    return grouped_words
```

`df['new_col'] = df[' input_text'].apply(split_text)`

Then repeat rows for each value of the list like this?

```
df_new = df.new_col.apply(pd.Series).stack().rename('new').reset_index()
pd.merge(df_new,df,left_on='level_0',right_index=True, suffixes=(['','_old']))[df.columns]
```